# Is this a bug in the boost library

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I'm compiling a project with autotools and am using g++ in version `gcc version 5.3.1` and boost version `1_63`. After `aclocal`, `autoconf`, `autoheader`, automake --add-missing, I ran `configure` with some options, which succedded and build make a Makefile. Running make fails and gives me the error (excerpt):

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/ratio/ratio.hpp:46:0,
             from /usr/local/include/boost/chrono/duration.hpp:41,
             from /usr/local/include/boost/chrono/time_point.hpp:33,
             from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/lock_types.hpp:22,
             from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/mutex.hpp:16,
             from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/mutex.hpp:16,
             from src/cosupport-initializer/cpp/BasicInitializer.cpp:39:
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:83:46: error: 'CHAR_MIN' was not declared in this scope
public detail::integer_traits_base<char, CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX>
                                          ^
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:83:56: error: 'CHAR_MAX' was not declared in this scope
public detail::integer_traits_base<char, CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX>
                                                    ^
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:83:64: error: template argument 2 is invalid
public detail::integer_traits_base<char, CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX>
                                                            ^
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:83:64: error: template argument 3 is invalid
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:89:53: error: 'SCHAR_MIN' was not declared in this scope
public detail::integer_traits_base<signed char, SCHAR_MIN, SCHAR_MAX>
                                                 ^
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:89:64: error: 'SCHAR_MAX' was not declared in this scope
 public detail::integer_traits_base<signed char, SCHAR_MIN, SCHAR_MAX>
                                                            ^
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:89:73: error: template argument 2 is invalid
public detail::integer_traits_base<signed char, SCHAR_MIN, SCHAR_MAX>
                                                                     ^
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:89:73: error: template argument 3 is invalid
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:95:58: error: 'UCHAR_MAX' was not declared in this scope
public detail::integer_traits_base<unsigned char, 0, UCHAR_MAX>
                                                      ^
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:95:67: error: template argument 3 is invalid
public detail::integer_traits_base<unsigned char, 0, UCHAR_MAX>
                                                               ^
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:131:47: error: 'SHRT_MIN' was not declared in this scope
public detail::integer_traits_base<short, SHRT_MIN, SHRT_MAX>
                                           ^
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:131:57: error: 'SHRT_MAX' was not declared in this scope
public detail::integer_traits_base<short, SHRT_MIN, SHRT_MAX>
                                                     ^
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:131:65: error: template argument 2 is invalid
public detail::integer_traits_base<short, SHRT_MIN, SHRT_MAX>
                                                             ^
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:131:65: error: template argument 3 is invalid
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:137:59: error: 'USHRT_MAX' was not declared in this scope
public detail::integer_traits_base<unsigned short, 0, USHRT_MAX>
                                                       ^
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:137:68: error: template argument 3 is invalid
public detail::integer_traits_base<unsigned short, 0, USHRT_MAX>
                                                                ^
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:143:45: error: 'INT_MIN' was not declared in this scope
public detail::integer_traits_base<int, INT_MIN, INT_MAX>
                                         ^
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:143:54: error: 'INT_MAX' was not declared in this scope
public detail::integer_traits_base<int, INT_MIN, INT_MAX>
                                                  ^
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:143:61: error: template argument 2 is invalid
public detail::integer_traits_base<int, INT_MIN, INT_MAX>
                                                         ^
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:143:61: error: template argument 3 is invalid
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:149:57: error: 'UINT_MAX' was not declared in this scope
public detail::integer_traits_base<unsigned int, 0, UINT_MAX>
                                                     ^
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:149:65: error: template argument 3 is invalid
public detail::integer_traits_base<unsigned int, 0, UINT_MAX>
                                                             ^
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:155:46: error: 'LONG_MIN' was not declared in this scope
public detail::integer_traits_base<long, LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX>
                                          ^
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:155:56: error: 'LONG_MAX' was not declared in this scope
public detail::integer_traits_base<long, LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX>
                                                    ^
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:155:64: error: template argument 2 is invalid
public detail::integer_traits_base<long, LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX>
                                                            ^
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:155:64: error: template argument 3 is invalid
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:161:58: error: 'ULONG_MAX' was not declared in this scope
public detail::integer_traits_base<unsigned long, 0, ULONG_MAX>
                                                      ^
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:161:67: error: template argument 3 is invalid
public detail::integer_traits_base<unsigned long, 0, ULONG_MAX>
```

This means e.g. that in `/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp` on line 83, the constructor initialization fails:

```
template<>
class integer_traits<char>
  : public std::numeric_limits<char>,
    public detail::integer_traits_base<char, CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX>
{ };
```

This means in the file `/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp` and headers included in it, there's no definition of `CHAR_MIN`. So this is a bug in boost? Or what am I missing here?

**UPDATE**

The relevant code excerpts. Before the move:

```
#include <CoSupport/compatibility-glue/nullptr.h>
#include <CoSupport/Initializer/BasicInitializer.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <cassert>

namespace CoSupport {
...
}
```

After the move:

```
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <CoSupport/compatibility-glue/nullptr.h>
#include <CoSupport/Initializer/BasicInitializer.hpp>
#include <cassert>

namespace CoSupport {
...
}
```

Comment: Show us the actual source code. What happens if you move the `#include` from line 39 up to line 1?

Comment: Still the same error. I placed  it on the first line (after the comments): `from src/cosupport-initializer/cpp/BasicInitializer.cpp:35:
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:83:46: error: 'CHAR_MIN' was not declared in this scope
     public detail::integer_traits_base<char, CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX>`

Comment: Then this looks like a bug, since Boost violates the principle that each header should include all other headers it needs. When you `#include  <limits.h>` before, does it work?

Comment: But wait, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/boost/limits.hpp already includes `<limits>`, so something else must be wrong. Check whether you have defined any header file that conflicts with the existing headers.

Comment: @RolandIllig It's not `<limits>` that defines CHAR_{MIN,MAX}, but `<climits>`. Seems like a bug in boost.

Comment: So, I could circumvent this by installing an older boost version?

Comment: You could probably `#include <climits>` before including that boost header, and it might work

Comment: @Chris Beck: Still gives me the same errors.

Comment: I don't get it, no matter where I include `<climits>`, `<limits>`, i.e. in `CoSupport/Initializer/BasicInitializer.hpp` or in `/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp`, I always get the same error.

Comment: one possibillity is, one of your header files opens a namespace and never closes it by accident, then afte it is included, boost and std headers get included within that namespace. then, symbol lookup after that point can fail in many wierd ways

Comment: Thanks for your effort, thsi sounds loical. Nevertheless the project wasn't build by me and I built it in the meantime in a different way

Comment: @FloriHe I suggest that you go recursively through the include tree and check all non standard headers (such as `CoSupport` ones) and look for macro definitions (header guards in particular) that are reserved to the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

> This means in the file `/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp` and headers included in it, there's no definition of `CHAR_MIN`

Which is as it should be - `CHAR_MIN` is defined in [`<climits>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/climits).

> So this is a bug in boost? Or what am I missing here?

With 99% certainty, this is not a bug in boost. You probably have some include files of your own, in your project's include directories, masking `climits` or `limits.h`, or possibly another file which `interger_traits.hpp` includes and itself includes `climits` or `limits.h`.