# Boost 1.53 compile errors

Tags: boost, gcc7

I tried to compile some sources with boost-1.53, g++-7.4 on WSL Ubuntu (Windows 10) but got an error:

```
/usr/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp:84:46: error: ‘CHAR_MIN’ was not declared in this scope
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41777947/253056

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15724357/253056

Comment: Thank you. But I couldn't figure out where `limits.h` masked. There's no include guards, neither file names that are crossed.

Comment: Look at preprocessor output to see what’s going on (`g++ -E`).

Comment: I did, i DID... bug couldnt